# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have made a system authentication using `node.js` and `PostgreSQL` and `react.js`. When the user has the access permission to the home page he should see some information I quired from the database, but I got nothing in the home page and I see this error on the console:

> Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

The code in for home component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            newquestion: ""
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        //console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            newquestion: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        axios
            .post("/questions", {
                question: this.state.newquestion
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get("/questions")
            .then(response => {
                const msg = response.data.msg;
                this.setState({ items: msg });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Add Question"
                        value={this.state.newquestion}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />

                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-default"
                        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </button>

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span>
                            <b>{this.state.items[0].username}</b>
                        </span>
                        <br />
                        {this.state.items[0].question}
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>
                            <span>
                                <b>Admin</b>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                            {this.state.items[0].answer}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

And this code from the backend

```
router.get('/questions', (req, res, next) => {
  pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
           res.json({success:false, msg:"can not connect to the DB" + err})
       }
       client.query('SELECT * FROM questions', function (err, result) {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            res.json({success: true, msg: result.rows})
        })
   })
});
```

Please can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Thanks and kind Regards.

Comment: can you show response data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though your `items` array is empty. This could be for one of two reasons. #1 On initial load, items has not been loaded yet from your axios AJAX request and the array is still empty, or #2 your database is not returning any data in `/questions`.

Either way the solution is the same. If you are going to use the `items[0]` syntax you need to do a length check on `items` to ensure it at least has 1 question, or else you are attempting to render an array item that does not exist.

Comment: I am afraid this is just like a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is in fact a solution to the problem and I prescribe exactly what he should do. Which part of my answer is unclear?

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "abed",
            "question": "how are you ?",
            "answer": "i am fine and you ?"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "morad",
            "question": "what is react?",
            "answer": "React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Abdullatif Yeah, then it is because your `items` array is undefined until the API request comes back and sets `items` to the data. I would put an if-statement above panel-heading and panel-body to check that the array length is greater than 0. i.e. `if(this.state.items.length > 0) { // panel-heading and panel-body}`
This will prevent your render function from rendering the `items` data until the response comes back from the server.

Comment: @WillGarcia I did as you said and it is working now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The component will be rendered as soon as its mounted and won't wait till you get the response from `/questions` api call. When you receive the response, the component's state will be updated and rendered again.

That's why when this line executes, `items` will still be an empty array.

```
<b>{this.state.items[0].username}</b>
```

You could conditionally render the component only when the `items` array has values.

```
render() {
  if(!items.length) return null;

  // if not, proceed with your render login
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`this.state.items` is an empty array at initial render, so `this.state.items[0]` is undefined, causing the error.

You can populate it in the initial state declaration:

```
this.state = {
  items: [{}],
  ...
}
```

Or if you are just using the first item, why not change the API endpoint to return a single object as the result instead of an array? Then on the front-end you can initialize with `this.state = { item: {} }` and refer to it via `this.state.item.username`.

Comment: actually, I wanna to use all the element in the array but I used items[0] only for checking if it is working or not.
I think it is rendering the template before getting the data from server

Comment: Yes that's what i meant by initial render. `componentDidMount`/`axios.get` is async so it'll render without the server data first. So you need to initialize it with some placeholder value to avoid getting an error.